# How to read '08E55' as string from Excel Using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

In excel i have value in a Column as '**08E55**'. The value is product ID and should be read as it is.
While reading the excel through pandas it is being converted as '**8e+55**' .
How can i avoid this?

Few records include values like -
U8716
U8715
8725
U8716
U8721
08E55

I have tried following things -

xls = pd.ExcelFile("New.xlsx")

sheet = xls.parse("Sheet1", dtype={'col': 'str'},convert_float = False)

Steps to reproduce the problem -

Create a new Excel File and add a record 08E55 without changing any Data Type in Excel and Try to read the value in Pandas.

Expected Output - 08E55

Current Output - 8e+55 or 8.000000e+55

Comment: do you want to read the whole number or read it as string?

Comment: I want to read it as '08E55'

Comment: I think you have to change the data type in the excel file because when I typed '08E55' in excel, it automatically converted into exponential form. if you change the data type in excel it does not happen

Comment: @Ravi I dont have control over excel. I cannot change the data type in excel.

Comment: I think in excel itself, it was in the exponential form. otherwise, it would work when you define data types.

Comment: whats the actual raw value in excel? setting the value to ="08E55" then reading it into excel works fine. I suspect its actually a number and your just looking at a exponential via excel.

Comment: If you guys are trying just create a new excel file and add value as "08E55" without changing any data type in excel. Now when you read it via Pandas it will show as exponential.

Comment: @user8523750 I've just done that and I was able to read the column as is, might be specific to your version of excel and pandas, you should add that to your question.

Comment: @Manakin My Pandas version is 1.1.4 and Excel 2010 Version 14. Can you share your pandas version. Maybe i can try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple, just use the converters parameter while reading the excel file.

```
pd.read_excel('New.xlsx', converters={'column_name':str})
```

**Edit 1:**

```
pd.read_excel('New.xlsx', converters={'column_name':str}, convert_float=False)
```

**Edit 2:**

```
pd.read_excel('new.xlsx', convert_float=False, dtype='str')
```

**Edit 3:**

```
df = pd.read_excel('new.xlsx', convert_float=False, dtype='str')

for val in df.itertuples():
    if '+' in df.at[val[0], 'prod_no'] or 'e' in df.at[val[0], 'prod_no'] or 'E' in df.at[val[0], 'prod_no']:
        df.at[val[0], 'prod_no'] = '0'+df.at[val[0], 'prod_no'].replace('e+', 'E')
    
    else:
        continue

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  prod_no
0   08E55
```

Comment: It returns 8.000000e+55  which i dont want. I want the value to return as  '08E55'.

Comment: Try the new one. So basically it is converting the float values first and then changing to string. This I believe should work.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but this is also not solving my problem.

Comment: Really? It worked in mine.
Can you provide a sample xlsx file via google drive or something?

It's hard to know till I get one that what exactly is causing the issue.

Comment: My Pandas version is 1.1.4 and Excel 2010 Version 14. Can you share your pandas version. Maybe i can try that.

Comment: Pandas version is same and this has nothing to do with Pandas version, nor the Excel, since its a xlsx file which works in any excel after 2010. I believe its because the way the values are saved on the excel sheet.

I really did create a file like you mentioned, and it works fine. Not sure what's the issue in your case.

I'll suggest make a dummy excel sheet, just copy that particular cell and put it randomly in a dummy column and share it. We can try something after that then.

Comment: You've created a csv, aren't you working with xlsx?
And all I see in the csv is 8.00E+55. How can I make this work buddy?

Comment: oops extremely sorry uploaded wrong file. Please find the updated link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mlGlQwq478uurf183ALvohL_UDfEXrEa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also the value is automatically getting converted into 8.00E+55 when written in Xlsx

Comment: Try the new edit. It should work this time I believe.

Comment: The Expected Output is  08E55. I am still getting  8e+55

Comment: The only thing I can suggest you after this, is a hack. Now I am able to get the string right? So why not manipulate it. See the new edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel('New.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', dtype={'col':str})
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not solving my problem.